# how to increase the performance of cmd command in window

Tags: java, window, arp

I am using java to call arp -s command and waiting for the process to finish in order to complete function .

```
String command ="arp -s "+entryIpAddress+" ee-ee-ee-ee-ee-ee-ee";
 Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);  
         p.waitFor();
```

but the calling of this process is taking more than the usual time so, is there a way to increase the performance of this method. i cannot remove the p.waitFor() my next function depend on the added entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't show any sign of effort towards allowing the process to complete *ever*. You are not consuming its output, so its output buffer will soon fill up, blocking further progress.

To make this task easier on yourself, please use the `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: like this  ProcessBuilder pr=new ProcessBuilder("arp -s "+"192.168.2.9"+" ee-ee-ee-ee-ee-ee-ee");
      pr.start();
  but how i can be sure that the process is finished

Comment: Study `ProcessBuilder`'s Javadoc with an emphasis on the treatment of the subprocess's standard output. If you want to analyze the subprocess's output in Java, you'll have to explicitly collect it into a `StringWriter` or similar.